# why refModel just uses "name" field?

Tags: atk4

please see this code:

```
$this->addField('user_id')->refModel("User");
```

this search for the "name" field by default! but I want to connect the username field. how can we define which field to be the refrence?

Answer (score 3):

in Model_User

```
$this->addField('name','username');
```

See this method:
https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/SQL/Model.php#L95

but this method is obsolete and you should use hasOne instead of it.

```
function hasOne($model,$our_field=null,$display_field=null,$as_field=null)
```

Comment: But the user model have both name and username fields!

Comment: actually refModel is obsolete
/** @obsolete use hasOne instead */
https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Field.php#L560

Comment: using hasOne you can define what field to show
https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/SQL/Model.php#L220